# how to save file image as original name

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I want to save output images using original name of image.

I try this code, but most cases work well, and a half save other file names. How to do it better?

```
cropped_images = "GrabCut"

if not os.path.exists(cropped_images):
    os.makedirs(cropped_images)

# Load data
filepath = "Data"
images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(filepath + "/*.jpg")]

file_names = []
for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
    org_image_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    file_names.append(org_image_name)

for i, image in enumerate(images):
    DO SOMETHING...

    img_name = file_names[i]
    cropped_images_path = os.path.join(cropped_images, img_name + '.jpg')

    cv2.imwrite(cropped_images_path, image)
```

Comment: Dunno if python goes through colection in order, but the simplest solution would be to store the output of `glob()` and then index the output together with images in last for loop.

Comment: @Croolman thanks, but how to do very simply in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have the error is because the lists made by `glob` and `os.listdir` are not the same, either different files (glob is only getting `jpg` files and `listdir` gets everything) or different order, or both.  You can change the filenames in a list, `orig_files`, to make a corresponding list of new filenames, `new_files`.

It also looks like it makes more sense to just read one image at a time (you only use them one at a time) so I moved that into the loop.  You can also use `os.path.basename` to get the filename, and `zip` to iterate through multiple lists together.

```
cropped_images = "GrabCut"

if not os.path.exists(cropped_images):
    os.makedirs(cropped_images)

# Load data
filepath = "Data"
orig_files = [file for file in glob.glob(filepath+"/*.jpg")]
new_files = [os.path.join(cropped_images, os.path.basename(f)) for f in orig_files]

for orig_f,new_f in zip(orig_files,new_files):
    image = cv2.imread(orig_f)

    DO SOMETHING...

    cv2.imwrite(new_f, image)
```